# JSP Request.getParameter() returning null

Tags: jsp, post, parameters, request

addTest.jsp

```
<form action="upload.jsp" method="post" name="inputFrom" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    Test_Name: <input type="text" name="test_nme"/>
    Test_Date: <input type="text" name="test_dte"/>
    File:<input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" values="submit"/>
</form>
```

upload.jsp

```
<%
    /* String test_name=(String)request.getAttribute("test_nme");
    String test_date=(String)request.getAttribute("test_dte");  
    out.println("CHANGED"+test_name+" "+test_date); */
    out.println(request.getParameter("test_nme")+" "+request.getParameter("test_dte"));
%>
```

I tried request.getAttribute and request.getParameter. But both are retunrning me null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` you can not directly get parameters by using `request.getParameter("test_nme");`

In this case the form fields aren't available as parameter of the request, they are included in the stream, so you need to get them from stream. A possible way is to use [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload//using.html). Here is sample code from official documentation ( Refer to 'Processing the uploaded items' section)

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
factory.setRepository(repository);

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

// Process the uploaded items
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

For a regular form field

```
 // Process a regular form field if (item.isFormField()) {
     String name = item.getFieldName();
     String value = item.getString();
     ... }
```